# How to find this functions family?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Cay you help me with this one? The original statement in Spanish is:

Encuentra una familia de funciones de la forma $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, de manera que, si se considera la función
$$
f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad f(x, y)=x+g(y)
$$
entonces la curva $\left\{(x, \tan x): x \in\left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)\right\}$ define la trayectoria de máxima inclinación que une dos de sus puntos de izquierda a derecha.

Rougly translates to:

Find a functions family   $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such as, if we consider  function
$$
f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad f(x, y)=x+g(y)
$$
then the curve $\left\{(x, \tan x): x \in\left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)\right\}$ defines the maximum tilt trajectory uniting two of its points from left to right.

Thanks in advance

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please add your own thoughts so we will see your efforts in the problem, this will be better for us to help you too.

Comment: The maximum tilt trajectory is defined by $\nabla f$ so $$\nabla f=(1,g'(y)y')$$ so the problem here is how I get from $g'(y)y'$ to $\tan x$
I was thinking $$\int g'(y)y'\,dx=\tan x$$ but I guess I am missing something